How to compare FileSystem's of two Path's in kotlin/java?
I was wondering how I could check if fileSystems of two different paths are equal. It seems wrong to write something like
path1.fileSystem == path2.fileSystem

because there could be a case when file systems are the same by meaning (they are fully identical), but in fact are different instances and because of that path1.fileSystem == path2.fileSystem may return false when it must actually return true. Then how should I compare file systems of two different paths? Or is == actually okay and works correctly in this situation?
I actually tried asking ChatGPT, but it gave me a weird solution that doesn't seem to work
boolean sameFileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault().provider().getScheme().equals(path1.getFileSystem().provider().getScheme())
                && FileSystems.getDefault().provider().getScheme().equals(path2.getFileSystem().provider().getScheme());



Update: I need to check this in order to resolve one path against another
(if the file systems are not the same I will just do something else, this part is irrelevant? i Just need to check if they are the same)

Did you actually observe the case where path1.fileSystem == path2.fileSystem returned false for the same file system or you just guess this may happen? Please note == in Kotlin doesn't check if the instance is exactly the same, but it uses the equals method. I'm not entirely sure if we can check filesystems for equality and the documentation isn't clear about this. But my point is: it is possible it works exactly as you expect.

What language are you using to perform this particular test.  Java or Kotlin?

What exactly do you want to find out semantically with this check. Why would you want to know if it's the same FileSystem? What is it that is based on that distinction?

Do you require the same filesystem or rather the same provider? Your update does not help understanding your problem. Why do you need to use a different path when the filesystem are different?

@Holger by "use a different path" I meant I'll just do something else, it's not really important, I jsut need to check if two file systems are the same so I can resolve one path against the other

“so I can resolve one path against the other”—you can resolve a path against another if they both belong to the same filesystem provider; they don’t need to belong to the same filesystem. And even if they do not belong to the same provider, just converting the second path to a string and calling resolve(String) instead of resolve(Path) will do in 99% of all cases. If you actually want to do A but resort to B in certain cases, it is important to know what B is, as it helps understanding why you don’t proceed with A despite A is what you actually want.

@Holger this actually answers my question, thank you very much!

If you want to know whether you can safely invoke .resolve(Path) for two existing Path instances, you must check whether the two path belong to the same provider, rather than filesystem.
Providers can be compared using the == operator; they are supposed to be singletons.
For comparison, this is how Files.copy(…) checks whether the two paths belong to the same filesystem provider:

public static Path copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
    throws IOException
{
    FileSystemProvider provider = provider(source);
    if (provider(target) == provider) {
        // same provider
        provider.copy(source, target, options);
    } else {
        // different providers
        CopyMoveHelper.copyToForeignTarget(source, target, options);
    }
    return target;
}

…
private static FileSystemProvider provider(Path path) {
    return path.getFileSystem().provider();
}


In most cases, a fallback using .resolve(String) works when you need to resolve with paths of different filesystem providers:
static Path resolveWithForeignSupport(Path base, Path other) {
    FileSystem fs1 = base.getFileSystem(), fs2 = other.getFileSystem();

    if(fs1.provider() == fs2.provider()) {
        return base.resolve(other);
    }

    if(other.getNameCount() <= 1 || fs1.getSeparator().equals(fs2.getSeparator())){
        return base.resolve(other.toString());
    }

    Path resolved = base, othersRoot = other.getRoot();
    if(othersRoot != null) {
        resolved = resolved.resolve(othersRoot.toString());
    }
    for(Path component: other) {
        resolved = resolved.resolve(component.toString());
    }
    return resolved;
}

